# implementing SeekBarPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-8.0-oreo, seekbarpreference

I'm having trouble implementing SeekBarPreference in a class.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/SeekBarPreference.html

As you see this SeekBarPreference is available in 25.1.0 and I implemented it in xml and UI looks fine. I need to save the value of this seekbar in default shared preferences. That is where I'm having the issue, there isn't an import option for    android.support.v7.preference.SeekBarPreference. Is it unused now?

I updated my app to have 26.0.1 and tried manually added the import but it's not setting in. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include the preference-v7 library in your dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:26.0.0'
```

and then you will be able to import the class with

```
import android.support.v7.preference.SeekBarPreference;
```

if your're compiling with sdk version 26, support library version should be 26.0.0, at the moment this is the [latest version](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html). 26.0.1 doesn't seem to exist